# How to run a java application jar which has Look & feel from .asp(classic ASP)

Tags: java, jquery, jar, asp-classic, cmd

I have first.asp after login there i have code

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


                           function runMyCommand() {
                               var xmlhttp7 = new XMLHttpRequest();             

                               xmlhttp.open("POST", "mporter_launch.asp", true);
                               xmlhttp.send();
                           }
  </script>
```

running this on click of a button and on mporter_launch.asp page i write

```
     Set wshshell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    'wshshell.run "cmd.exe /c java -jar ""C:\Program Files\Pap\WZ\Server\bin\mporter.jar"" ""C:\wz-licence.txt""" 1 false

                                Set wshshell=Nothing
```

this run cmd.exe and java.exe and i hope also my jar mporter.jar run but the look & feel didn't pop up like i run this using command prompt. Have any Idea how to do it. thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe that's a stupid question but does your java app run when you start it directly from the console?

Comment: yes it run directly using console and also if i run it using .vbs file where i write code to run this jar from console, I think  it run but look feel not visible to me...